# Handling input for a game engine

Tags: c++, game-engine

I want to make a game engine in c++ but I am struggling to find resources on how to get input in a sensible way. Is there a way that I can achieve this without using a library?

Comment: C++ has no notion of keyboard nor mouse, that is OS-specific. Libraries like GLFW "just" wrap the OS-specific APIs in a uniform one.

Comment: So I should just use a premade library instead of trying to architect a library from scratch.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best way.

Comment: @Breadleaf I mean you are attempting to make a game engine from scratch... so I guess it is up to you what you want to focus on, I would use a pre-made library since it wouldn't be particularly interesting topic for me.